# Running a MVC project in a computer which has .NET Framework 4.7.1

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

Can a MVC 4 or MVC 5 project having the target framework of 4.0 be run on a computer witch has .NET framework 4.7.1 installed. Or should I explicitly install .NET framework 4.0 ?

My MVC project is unloaded in VS 2017 and VS 2019 even after installing ASP .NET MVC 4.
[image]

Comment: `Can a MVC 4 or MVC 5 project having the target framework of 4.0 be run on a computer witch has .NET framework 4.7.1 installed.` Yes.

Comment: @mjwills thank you for the reply. Is there any reason why my project gets unloaded in VS 2017. In he outpu i get error as "The imported project .build\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk." . But the target file is there.

Comment: When you say run do you mean "in Visual Studio"? Since that is quite a different question.

Comment: @mjwills yes actually i am trying to load in visual studio 2017 to do some solution maintenance. The project unloads from the solution

Answer (score 0):

you will have to install require framework